# Rails if function not submitting before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I am trying to set a boolean based on the value of another field.

However, the console output fires a not-null violation:

```
  Gin Create (124.6ms)  INSERT INTO "gins" ("gin_name", "snippet", "description", "abv", "created_at", "updated_at", "slug") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["gin_name", "Seedlip"], ["snippet", "Alcohol free gin"], ["description", "Seedlip have inspired alcohol free gin"], ["abv", 0.0], ["created_at", "2019-02-01 09:21:30.080931"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-01 09:21:30.080931"], ["slug", "seedlip"]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "alcoholic" violates not-null constraint)
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (56, Seedlip, Alcohol free gin, Seedlip have inspired alcohol free gin, 0, 2019-02-01 09:21:30.080931, 2019-02-01 09:21:30.080931, null, seedlip, null).
: INSERT INTO "gins" ("gin_name", "snippet", "description", "abv", "created_at", "updated_at", "slug") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"
```

**gin table**

```
  create_table "gins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "gin_name"
    t.string "snippet"
    t.text "description"
    t.float "abv"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "distillery_id"
    t.string "slug"
    t.boolean "alcoholic"
```

**model gin.rb**

```
class Gin < ApplicationRecord

    before_create :is_alcoholic

    has_one :distillery
    has_many :botanicals_gin
    has_many :botanicals, through: :botanicals_gin

    validates :gin_name, :snippet, :description, presence: true
    validates :gin_name, uniqueness: true

    def is_alcoholic
      if abv > 0.1
        alcoholic = true
      end
    end
```

I have tried a few different callbacks before_save (I understand this would run `is_alcoholic` on new and updated records) and before_validation (not sure this is applicable as I don't have a validation in the model for `alcoholic`.

From the console I don't have a clear sense of whether that function is even attempting to run.

Am I overlooking something basic?

**Update**
Thanks to the answers below, I've now got the following which works for both conditions:

```
def is_alcoholic
  if abv == 0.0
    self.alcoholic = false
  else
    self.alcoholic = true
  end
end
```

I have modelled the column as I wish to use it as a filter in search.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `self` to the `is_alcoholic` method:

```
def is_alcoholic
  if abv > 0.1
    self.alcoholic = true
  end
end
```

if you dont use `self` in this method, ruby just denote a local variable `alcoholic = true`, but you actually refer to attribute.

Comment: This is just applicable for setter method call. +1

Answer (score 0):

The log states that you are attempting to create a record where `abv` is `0.0`. Therefore the condition you formulated in `is_alcoholic` will be false which leads to `alcoholic` not having a value.

Try changing the implementation to:

```
def is_alcoholic
  self.alcoholic = abv > 0.1
end
```

That way, there will always be a value set for `alcoholic` and it is more descriptive anyway.

Comment: I'm still getting the not-null violation.

Comment: @SimonCooper It would be more convenient if you can set by default as false `t.boolean "alcoholic", default: false`

Comment: Well actually I would't model the column at all if it will always be equally described by the condition `abv > 0.1`. Adding a scope will do just the same then, and will not duplicate information.